# Angular 4 PWA Service Worker doesn't update when new updates available

Tags: javascript, angular, service-worker

After i update my Angular 4 PWA app and deployed , user not getting new updates until user clear the cache and refresh the browser.
Sw doesn't update.
Even i press the update button in crome Dev it doesn't update I have to clear the cache and refresh the browser.

I used these packages
@angular/service-worker @angular/platform-server ng-pwa-tools

Comment: Have you found a solution to this issue? I am having the same problem even with setting cache headers to not cache.

Comment: No... I haven't if u using workbox 2 that's possible to do..i update sw manifest cache life to 0 .but still won't update..

Comment: Same here, but I'm using angular 5 with the SW native from angular-cli. Have you find any solution?

Answer (score 6):

Make sure your app **checks for updates** from the server from **time to time**.

In the `app.component.ts` add `private swUpdate: SwUpdate` into the constructor.

```
 this.swUpdate.available.subscribe(event => {
   if (confirm('Update Available. Refresh the page now to update the cache.')) {
     location.reload(true);
   } else {
     console.log('continue with the older version');
   }
 });

 setInterval(() =>  {
   this.swUpdate.checkForUpdate();
 }, 21600);
```

Comment: This solved the problem for me! This after doing quite much searching on the Internet, why have I not found this solution anywhere else, - are there any drawbacks? For me this seems to work perfect.

Comment: Well the only drawback is it will check for the updates every 21600 milliseconds which might not be very ideal for the mobile web since it might consume a bit of data. Obviously we can change the amount of time we check for updates. My application was in production for over a year now and haven't had any issues with this.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the information you've provided I guess your web server is serving the SW file with some caching headers and the visitors' browsers use the cached version.

Be sure to explicitly set the caching headers to no-cache/-1/etc. so that the browser always checks the web server for a new version of the service-worker.js (or whatever) file.

Comment: @shashikthiwanka No, the headers are set by the web server you're using to serve your app to the users. It's where you deploy your code. You can check the headers of your service-worker.js by this tool: http://www.webconfs.com/http-header-check.php I suggest you read these: https://www.mnot.net/cache_docs/ and  https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/optimizing-content-efficiency/http-caching

Comment: Maintain an Etag at the server solves my problem partially means 7/10 times it's working correctly

Comment: @GauravSharma wouldn't no-cache/public/no-store/-1 work better? That way it would be explicit. I have found ETags to be unreliable sometimes. In the case of the SW you really don't want to hold on it; the client should always validate it. Also, it's not one of the critical path assets so the request doesn't delay the page.