# Angular PWA doesn't update in production

Tags: angular, progressive-web-apps, aws-amplify

I have a PWA in Angular 8. I have added `$ ng add @angular/pwa`, and the PWA functionality seems to work, accept for this problem: when I push a new build to production, the app is **not** updated on people's browsers (tested on Chrome and mobile Safari).

Instead, when a user opens their browser to go to the app, he/she will see the previous (non-updated) version of the app that was previously on their browser.

They will only see the newer version if they refresh the page. No errors are shown.

I push to production using `$ ng build --prod`, and then insert the build into AWS Amplify.

The app should always update to the newest build when a user opens it in a browser. That is not happening.

I have seen discussion of this on Stack Overflow from the last few years, such as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48146332/angular5-pwa-doesnt-refresh-service-workers) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46179907/angular-4-pwa-service-worker-doesnt-update-when-new-updates-available). But these questions don't have accepted answers, and the advice given are about implementing workarounds.

What is the solution to this issue?

---

In my case, the app is being iterated a lot, and it pulls a lot of local assets. So a user still seeing a build from a week ago is a significant issue. I am hoping this is not the expected behavior--bc that is a big drawback to PWA functionality if it is.

In the [Angular docs](https://angular.io/guide/service-worker-config#updatemode) there is some discussion of "updateMode", but it looks to me like my settings are already in place to work properly, but the issue remains. Here is my ngsw-config.json:

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/service-worker/config/schema.json",
  "index": "/index.html",
  "assetGroups": [
    {
      "name": "app",
      "installMode": "prefetch",
      "resources": {
        "files": [
          "/favicon.ico",
          "/index.html",
          "/manifest.webmanifest",
          "/*.css",
          "/*.js"
        ]
      }
    }, {
      "name": "assets",
      "installMode": "lazy",
      "updateMode": "prefetch",
      "resources": {
        "files": [
          "/assets/**",
          "/*.(eot|svg|cur|jpg|png|webp|gif|otf|ttf|woff|woff2|ani)"
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: try to use the pwa features like SwUpdate ..so you can listen for new version (checked by the ngsw.json file) and if so .. maybe force a relaod of the app and clear local storage